# Teams calendar requests causes Exchange Server 2016 to log unhandled exception (maxQueryStringLength)

Tags: microsoft-teams, exchange-server-2016

Teams calendar requests causes Exchange Server 2016 to log unhandled exception (maxQueryStringLength)

Our on-premises Exchange Server 2016 is logging unhandled exceptions – it appears to be Teams querying calendar data via REST API.

In the event log: (example.com is our on-premises Exchange Server)

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value.
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)

Request information: 
    Request URL: https://example.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarView?$top=0&$select=attendees,body,categories,end,hasAttachments,iCalUId,id,isAllDay,isCancelled,isOrganizer,isReminderOn,location,locations,onlineMeetingUrl,organizer,originalEndTimeZone,originalStartTimeZone,reminderMinutesBeforeStart,responseRequested,responseStatus,sensitivity,seriesMasterId,showAs,start,subject,type&startDateTime=2020-03-25T20:46:37Z&endDateTime=2020-03-25T21:46:37Z&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name SkypeTeamsMeetingUrl' or PropertyId eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name SkypeTeamsProperties' or PropertyId eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name SchedulingServiceUpdateUrl' or PropertyId eq 'Integer {00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x8217' or PropertyId eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name OnlineMeetingConferenceId' or PropertyId eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name OnlineMeetingTollNumber' or PropertyId eq 'Binary {6ed8da90-450b-101b-98da-00aa003f1305} Id 0x0023' or PropertyId eq 'Boolean {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name DoNotForward' or PropertyId eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name ClientOptimisticEventId' or PropertyId eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name OnlineMeetingConfLink' or PropertyId eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name TeamsVtcConferenceId' or PropertyId eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name TeamsVtcTenantId' or PropertyId eq 'String {6ed8da90-450b-101b-98da-00aa003f1305} Name OnlineMeetingConferenceId' or PropertyId eq 'String {6ed8da90-450b-101b-98da-00aa003f1305} Name OnlineMeetingTollNumber'),multiValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'StringArray {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name OnlineMeetingTollFreeNumbers' or PropertyId eq 'StringArray {6ed8da90-450b-101b-98da-00aa003f1305} Name OnlineMeetingTollFreeNumbers')
```

Comment: Did you try to update the maxQueryStringLength in your config file?

Comment: Thank you, we made the change today and will monitor.

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm.

Comment: I accepted M. Warren's answer.  It had the most details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\rest\web.config"

Add

> maxQueryStringLength="10240"

to

> < httpRuntime  />

e.g.
< httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" maxUrlLength="2048" **maxQueryStringLength="10240"** requestPathInvalidCharacters="<,>,*,%,\,?" 
requestValidationMode="2.0" />

I might be out on the size by a mile (max string was ~1956bytes) but this was annoying me to no end.

Comment: Thank you, we made the change today and will monitor.

Comment: Thanks, I missed seeing the 'checkmark' for accepting the answer, I have accepted your answer now.

Answer (score -1):

Update the maxQueryStringLength in web.config file.

Comment: M. Warren's answer is better because it specified detailed location and format.